# Create SPARQL endpoint via ISQL in Virtuoso

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I have to create dozens of custom SPARQL endpoints in Virtuoso and assign a particular named graph to a particular endpoint.
I know there is a Conductor GUI but I would not like to create endpoints manually.
How do I create an endpoint (say, on port 8899) via Virtuoso ISQL command line?

Comment: What is "create an endpoint"? That's not a well-defined expression in SPARQL. If you mean a graph, it's `CREATE GRAPH <URI>`.

Comment: In Virtuoso Conductor you can navigate to Web Services -> Virtual Directories and create a new VHost with the SPARQL access point on this VHost. The problem is that it's done manually, I'm looking for a way how to use ISQL commands of Virtuoso to create them automatically.